# DataGridView и несколько таблиц базы данных

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Возникла необходимость отобразить отдельные столбцы разных таблиц из БД в DataGridView.
В источнике данных я подключил 2 таблицы. Зашел в правку столбцов и выбрал необходимые столбцы из 2-х таблиц, но столбцы 1-ой из таблиц при отображении всегда пустые.

Можно ли как-то одновременно привязать несколько `'table_name'BindingSource`-ов (в моем случае `userBindingSource` и `testBindingSource`)? И вообще какие технологии обычно используют, когда надо выводить много данных из разных таблиц? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Опишу структуру таблиц классами C#

```
//Таблица заявок
public class Orders
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Comment{get;set;}
    public int Created {get;set;}
    public int CreatorId {get;set;}
}

//таблица Пользователей
public class Authors
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FisrtName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string FullName {get;set;}
}
```

делаем запрос который вернет нам необходимые данные
например:

```
select
    o.Id,
    o.Comment,
    o.Created,
    a.FullName
from orders o
inner join Authors a
    on o.CreatorId=a.Id
```

полученный результат запроса "привязываем" к DataGrid.
Либо можно сформировать [представление](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190174.aspx) на стороне сервера а из приложения обращаться к данному представлению

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего создать sql-запросик, который вернет готовую результирующую таблицу для DataGridView. Нам же только смотреть.

Comment: То есть программно в класс DataTable загрузить SqlDataReader , который возвращает данный запроса ? Просто хотелось бы как-то не загружать огромную БД в программу , памяти много может портебоваться.Хотя может я не так что-то понял.

Answer (score 0):

Можно связать таблицы по какому - нибудь полю и выводить всю нужную информацию обращаясь к одной таблице. Связывать можно по айдишнику например или по соотношению - фамилия -> зарплата.